# .fig files not opening in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I''ve saved a matlab figure as .fig file and when I'm trying to open it its not opened. I don't know why? so if any one could help me.

This is the code used to save the figure:

```
h=figure('visible','off'); imagesc(m); colormap(jet(4096)); colorbar; title('mean');
filename = strcat(name,'_mean');
imPath=strcat(name,'/',filename);
saveas(h,imPath,'fig');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code worked fine for me. try changing your figure visibility from 'off' to 'on'

Answer (score 3):

First, when creating the figure change `'visible','off'` to `'visible','on'`

If you can't do that for some reason, open the figure from the command line or using File->Open and then type `>>figure(1)` (assuming that is the only figure you have open) at the command line.  This should display the figure.